# how use ajax to custom page template

Tags: theme-development, ajax, json

i'm completely new to WordPress ajax .
i'm working on new custom template . there is a custom form which stores data on custom database .
for search section i need to use Ajax . then i found one way , that is create new template page which called json.php for example . it echoing the data in json formating .

is that way correct way for using ajax ?
what's the better way ?
anyone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> then i found one way , that is create new template page which called json.php for example . it echoing the data in json formating .

**No.** You should never make direct requests to php files inside a theme or plugin, and you don't need to create page templates to handle AJAX requests.

If you need to handle a form, make the request to the same page that served the form and inspect the POST/GET variables.

*If you need to make an AJAX request using javascript*, do it to the REST API. [You can register an endpoint URL](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) with a pretty url that will respond with JSON that can be easily processed in javascript.

When registering the endpoint, you tell it the name you want for the URL, e.g. `/wp-json/hossein/v1/searchdatabase`, and you tell it a function to call when it's used. That function is where you do the searching of your database, and you return the data you want to send to the browser.

Comment: you save me from darkness bro ! tnx a lot and be lucky ...

Comment: if this answers your question could you mark it as the correct answer? it's the tick/check under the voting controls